Showing $\|Ax\|_2\leq\|x\|_*\leq\sqrt{n}\|Ax\|_2$
Show that for any real norm $||x||_{*}$, exists a matrix such that it holds $$||Ax||_{2} \leq ||x||_{*} \leq \sqrt{n} ||Ax||_{2},$$ finding an example where the upper bound it’s tight.
I feel this should be an application of ellipsoid theorem: for every K centrally symmetric(if $x$ lies in $K$ then $-x$ lies in $K$) convex body(convex,compact and full dimensional) exists an ellipsoid $\epsilon$ cantered in 0 and t in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $t+\epsilon \subseteq K \subseteq t + \sqrt{n}\epsilon$.
In particular I can find K as $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_{*} \leq 1\}$ and then with t=0 I find the ellipsoid defined as the image of a certain matrix so that I have the existence of $A$.
However, the inclusion doesn’t help me find a condition on the norm, since I’m considering different norms and I don’t know how to relate the two.
Any help would be appreciated.

Pick $A$, such that $A(\sqrt n\epsilon)$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $K\subset \sqrt n\epsilon$ implies that $AK\subset A(\sqrt n\epsilon)$, so $A$ as an operator from $(\mathbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_*)$ to $(\mathbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_2)$ is a contraction, i.e. $\|A\|\le 1$, therefore $\|Ax\|_2\le \|x\|_*$.
Similarly, $\epsilon\subset K$ implies that $\sqrt{n} \epsilon\subset \sqrt n K$, therefore $A^{-1}(\overline{B(1, 0)})=\sqrt n \epsilon\subset\sqrt n K$, $\|A^{-1}\|\le \sqrt n$, and $\forall y, \|A^{-1}(y)\|_*\le \sqrt n \|y\|_2$ Hence replace $y$ by $A(x)$, $\|x\|_*\le \sqrt n \|A(x)\|_2$.

Why does exists a vector satisfying $||x||_{*} = \sqrt{n}||Ax||_2$ for every matrix satisfying the two inequalities?
